# SQL data type for a money + char

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am new in creating reports using crystal reports and c#. I created a c# program which displays clients' allowance.My only problem for now is that a field is not displaying what I wanted. I have a table in my sql that has a 'varchar' data type because I want it to display a number with a text. My problem is that it doesn't put a comma when a value has a thousand separator. What I want is to display my value as **25,000/day** instead of **25000/day**. Is it possible to to this? What data type should I use?

Comment: Have you considered a separate column for the units?  Either a `VarChar` or, better yet, an id into a lookup table.  That would let add additional data, e.g. factors used in calculations like the number of days in a "week".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no data type supporting your requirement in SQL Server.

A better approach would be to use `decimal` for your numbers and a separate column for your text part i.e. `/day`. This will help you run queries requiring averages, minimum, maximum on the decimal field. Later you can format it in C# for your reports.

But if you can't change the database then you may split the string in c# based on character "/" and then you may use ToString() for formatting the number with commas. Something on the following lines:

```
    string str = "25000/day";
    string[] tempArray = str.Split('/');
    double number = 0;
    if(double.TryParse(tempArray[0],out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("###,###.#######") + "/" + tempArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you store it as a decimal and do the formatting when you display it, using [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)

```
string display = value.ToString("N") + "/day";
```

Storing just the decimal will take less space and also you can do calculations on the field easily later on if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Try using string.Format() method to format it.

```
string disp = String.Format( "{ 0:C}", Convert.ToInt32(value.split(@"/")[0])) + @"/" + value.split(@"/")[1];
```

where value is the value you need to display (i.e. "25000/day")

HTH.